# NSIS reading an unicode file name issue

Tags: unicode, filenames, nsis

I am trying to add a file with unicode name to my installer , when I copy and paste or insert the filename , it gives `??????.pdf` as characters, so in compilation it couldn't recognise the file and failed to open it .

```
File: failed opening file "..\???? ????????.pdf"
```

Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

With NSIS 2 all filenames have to be encoded in the active codepage (CP_ACP) and it will generate an ANSI API installer so the codepage on the end-users machine comes into play as well.

The NSIS 3 compiler is Unicode but to generate a Unicode installer you need to add `Unicode true` to your .nsi script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the standard NSIS version (2.46)?

Maybe you can try the [Unicode NSIS](http://www.scratchpaper.com/) or the new (alpha!) Version [NSIS 3.0a2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download).

Comment: In fact, I upgraded my version from 2.46 to 3.0a2, the compilation worked :  the unicode file name was accepted but when executing the installer my file was created with different name, expml for `File1??????.pdf` it keeps only `File1.pdf` :(

Comment: Have you tried Unicode NSIS? Maybe this has less bugs than the alpha of NSIS 3...

Comment: It's about unicode version , I tried 2.46-5 unicode version and it worked, thank you all for your time

Comment: Have you tried @Andres solution with NSIS 3 and the `Unicode true` command?

Comment: Sorry I didn't, I already uninstalled NSIS 3 and replaced it by 2.46-5 unicode before reading the answer, maybe I will give it a try later, will probably work.